# How do I retrieve the names of all checked checkboxes using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to get the names of all checked checkboxes.  I tried this:

```
$("#movebutton").click(function()   {
    var selectedids = "";           
    alert($('.checkbos_gruppe[checked=checked]').attr("name"));             
});
```

Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to loop through them, in this case [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) is a great choice to get an array of names, for example:

```
$("#movebutton").click(function()   {
  var selectednames = $('.checkbos_gruppe:checked').map(function() { 
                      return this.name; 
                    }).get();
  alert(selectednames.join(", "));
});
```

This will get you an array of the `name` attributes in `selectednames`, then use it however you want.  Make sure to use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) on the end so you get *just* an array of the names.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
var names = $('.checkbos_gruppe:checked').map(function(index, elem) {
    return this.name;
}).get();
```

Comment: `names` would be a jQuery object ;)

Comment: yay, happens if you use both `.map()` methods quite often :p fixed ;)